# Sum of two Poly Kernels

Tags: self-study, svm, kernel-trick

I have a questions from assignment about sum polynomial Kernels :

If I have Poly Kernel $k_1$ =$(α_1 x\cdot y+β_1)^d$ and mapping $\varphi_1$ 
and kernel $k_2$ =$(α_2 x\cdot y+β_2)^d$ with mapping  $\varphi_2$ .

I need to find a mapping $\varphi$ corresponds to the kernel K = $k_1$ + $k_2$
with the same dimension as $k_1$ , $k_2$

So far I know that the mapping of a polynomial kernel with degree $d$ is vector of all the monomials up to degree $d$ , 
And that mapping sum of two kernel function  K  will be $\varphi_1(x)\varphi_1(y)+\varphi_2(x)\varphi_2(y)$ .

Please advise how to procceed from here .

Comment: what are $\phi1$ and $\phi2$?